# Redirect subdomain to a specific folder only without the main domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have links like this one:

```
a.site.co.il
b.site.co.il
...
```

I configured the server to work with wild cards and redirect these subdomains into a folder on this IP:

```
62.90.154.000/goin
```

Then, I created a htaccess on 62.90.154.000 root so using of subdomain will redirect into a specific folder.
An example of this would be:

```
a.site.co.il  =>  62.90.154.000/goin
```

But the Ip will not redirect into goin folder, but to the IP itself:

```
62.90.154.000  =>  62.90.154.000
```

Here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(!62?|.*)$ goin/index.php?subdomain=$1 [L]
```

This seems to work, but the problem is that this htaccess also redicreds the main domain (62.90.154.000) into the subdomains' folder!
How can I solve this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(!62?|.*)$
```

Is just skipping REQUEST_URI that start with `/62`. It is not skipping your IP address.

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip below rule for IP addresses that start with 62.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^62\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^62\.
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.site\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /goin/$0 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ goin/index.php?subdomain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to completely clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Your example doesn't do redirect for subdomains. they all redirect to the same IP name.

Comment: Can you set a redirect rule so any subdomain like this: a.site.co.il redirects into some folder on my IP?

Comment: I am sorry this wasn't clear enough. I edited the question. so: a.site.co.il => 62.90.154.000/goin AND 62.90.154.000 => 62.90.154.000 (not 62.90.154.000/goin)

Comment: This, sort of, is working, but the url is changed with "/goin" on the end. Can you redirect the subdomain into goin folder without changing the url?

Comment: Ok, that was really fantastic, I removed the R=302 and it worked amazingly! now, How to set this rules for all subdomains, not just "a" one?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was genius :)

Comment: I am sorry, But I have a new issue now. I can't access another folders on my IP. for example, 62.90.154.000/dbadmin (phpmyadmin) will result in this error: "62.90.154.000 redirected you too many times ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". any idea?